# fiitting a normal distribution to a histogram in C++

Tags: c++, data-fitting

I am working on spectrum sensing in C++ and my problem until now is how to estimate the exact value of noise. So I did the histogram of my data and I want to fit a gaussian distribution to this histogram and then I have the mean of this fitting distribution like in matlab [mean,variance]=normfit(x).

```
vec noise::gauss_fit(vec spectrum_sensed,int Nfft)
{
    Histogram<double> hist;
    hist.setup(min(spectrum_sensed),max(spectrum_sensed),Nfft);
    // now I need to fit this histogram by a normal distribution "Normal"
    // and finally I get the mean of this distribution: normal.get_setup();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The normal distribution makes this quite easy:

```
mean = sum(spectrum_sensed)/N

variance = sum((spectrum_sensed-mean)^2)/N
```

You don't fit a histogram, you fit the data. And in the case of a normal distribution, there's no fitting involved as everything is analytical.

Comment: No i want to fit the front up of the histogram because my data is not normal distribution, it is received by radio.

Comment: @Mkachakh Are you aware that a normal distribution *is* a gaussian distribution? Otherwise I don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: yeah i know that are the same of course! But my question is how to fit a normal distribution to any histogrtam that it has no particular distribution!

Comment: @Mkachakh You can fit a normal distribution to any (even non-normally-distributed) data using the stuff in my answer. It will just be a very bad fit if the data isn't (nearly) normally distributed..

Comment: But i want to fit the gaussian curve to the first ascending slope of the histogram because i want to estimate the noise power.